# Updating a UITableViewController not visible on the Screen

Tags: ios

Here is my scenario. I have a product screen and a product details screen. Basically you can click on the product and go to the product details screen. Now, while I am on the product details screen I want to do some action like change the product name and I want that to reflect in the product screen when I go *back* using the back button.

How can I do that?

**Solutions I tried:**

I created a protocol on the product details controller and had product controller subscribe to that protocol. Every time I change the product name the protocol got triggered in the product controller but I was unable to change any UI elements on the product controller since the product controller was not currently visible.

Currently, I am reloading all the data on **viewWillAppear** which works but it means it makes a call to the server (iCloud) each time the view is loaded. This is causing long wait times.

Any recommendations?

Comment: If you modify the data structure that the table view is looking at and do a [tableView reload] on viewWillAppear will that not fix your issue?

Comment: This is the solution I currently have implemented. Please see the updated text in the question.

Comment: If you changed the product name, don't you have to do that change in the cloud too?

Comment: Yes, it changes in the cloud but I am talking about refreshing the product controller which is not visible on the screen. If I fetch the updated product name in the viewDidAppear then it is slow since viewDidAppear is fired a lot of times.

Answer (score 1):

On viewWillAppear you can update just the single cell where the data has changed. You know which was clicked on, so you can store a reference to that and then call:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

This will avoid updating the whole table and causing extra delays. If the table view is fast enough to scroll, where it is fetching data for each cell, then this will be fast enough too.

Comment: How can I store a reference to the selected NSIndexPath. If I store it in a property then it becomes null when the user comes back to the view.

Comment: At the top of your class you would do: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selctedPath; and then when they select a cell do: self.selectedPath = indexPath;    As your view controller is removed, it's just behind the other then the value of selectedPath will remain.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing! Even if I hardcoded and change the index 0 it does not updated the user interface of the product controller when I go back to it.

Comment: Are you sure you're modifying the data that the cell should be loading? have you logged it out?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to come back to this problem later. Currently I am not able to solve it.